# Geoportals in context of INSPIRE

Tags: geoportal

Do you know any geoportals which are fully (or almost) compatible with INSPIRE directive?

Answer (score 9):

The French INSPIRE compliant geoportal (or geoportail) is online at http://www.geoportail.fr/

Ireland's EPA is responsible for many INSPIRE compliant datasets: http://gis.epa.ie/ - more to come in 2011. Ireland is implementing a GeoNetworks Solution where all councils have their own portals that feed into a national hub run by central government. http://inspire.compass.ie/

There is also the EU portal itself (written with MapFish / OpenLayers) at http://www.inspire-geoportal.eu/index.cfm/pageid/321

Also see this OS project http://code.google.com/p/inspire-foss/ and demo Dutch site http://inspire.kademo.nl/

Answer (score 6):

*http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_for_Spatial_Information_in_the_European_Community*

**INSPIRE (DVDTI):**

1. Discovery - Metadata
2. View
3. Download
4. Transform
5. Invoke

There an OSS project on INSPIRE implementation:

http://wiki.deegree.org/deegreeWiki/InspireNode
code.google.com/p/inspire-foss/

Another one less advanced
jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-2684

Look for geoportals (sdi) solutions 
and see how they are advanced in the INSPIRE implementation:

www.inspire.esri.com/
news.pb.com/article_display.cfm?article_id=4640
www.geoconcept.com/The-French-National-Geoportal-in.html?var_recherche=inspire

You should ask on inspire-forum.jrc.ec.europa.eu/

Others documentations: 
inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/events/conferences/inspire_2010/conf_poster.cfm

Check this implementation:
www.epractice.eu/en/cases/sitridt

```
References: 
http://www.delicious.com/based2/inspire

inspire_discovery
inspire_metadata

inspire_view

inspire_download
```

inspire_transform

```
inspire_invoke
```

EDIT - [EU INSPIRE Geoportal project attribution](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27293490)

Answer (score 4):

I think [Lithuania](http://www.geoportal.lt/wps/portal/!ut/p/c1/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os_gAQwNnc09LYwN3QwMDA0-ToABzCy8fY39jc6B8JJK8haWnq4GRuYGhh6Wlu7u_lwlJug3Mg0C6PT1CwnxdjE2MDQnoDk7N0w8HuRi_GSjyqC709jDGKw_2AUjeAAdwNEDTj-pKgzAzfT-P_NxU_YLc0IgKz0xPXUdFRQDmN-YJ/dl2/d1/L2dJQSEvUUt3QS9ZQnB3LzZfUDEwQzdJOTMwODBHNzBJMDdSTzQwUTA4NTc!/) too has an INSPIRE geoportal

Answer (score 3):

EuroGeographics Association has launched a website on July 1 EuroGeoInfo acting point of access to spatial data in Europe.

Through the new website [www.eurogeoinfo.pl](http://www.eurogeoinfo.eu/) one can read about the infrastructures for spatial information in different countries and the products (Geoportals) and services offered by belonging to the association offices.